# assigning a variable to an object resulting a different value

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions

so, I'm using the notifications api to debug my extension for the status bar

and I have this code

```
this.statusBarItem.backgroundColor = bgc;
n.window.showInformationMessage(this.statusBarItem.backgroundColor + '');
n.window.showInformationMessage(bgc + '');
```

obviously, `bgc` is an instance of the `ThemeColor` class
the weird thing here is that, when logging `bgc`, it is an object BUT `this.statusBarItem.backgroundColor` is undefined, even though it should be the same as `bgc`.

I also tried logging the assignment itself, and it shows an object, so idk how did it change into undefined and why so.

I tried stuffs like `Object.defineProperty` too, but it doesn't change the result either, does anybody knows why?

Comment: How are you initializing `this.statusBarItem`?  That might be undefined.

Comment: I did `this.statusBarItem = n.window.createStatusBarItem(t.id, n.StatusBarAlignment[t.align], t.priority);`, `n` is the vscode module and `t` is an object passed as a class constructor param btw. Also if `this.statusBarItem` is undefined, shouldn't it be throwing an error instead?